# Don't have the pictures from directory on CollectionView

Tags: ios, directory, save, uicollectionview

I would want to show all the pictures in my directory however I am creating Folders in the Directory so that I can sort the pictures.  I want to show all of the pictures in several folders. I am using the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location=@"Bottoms"@"Top"@"Right"@"Left"@"Down"@"Up";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    collectionTrash.delegate =self;
    collectionTrash.dataSource=self;
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
        NSLog(@"i");
        NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
        if(data)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [allImagesArray addObject:image];
            NSLog(@"array:%@",[allImagesArray description]);
        }}}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    NSLog(@"j");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [allImagesArray count];


}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reuseID = @"ReuseID";
    TrashCell *mycell = (TrashCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageInCell = (UIImageView*)[mycell viewWithTag:1];
    imageInCell.image = [allImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"a");
    return mycell;
}
```

If you see my code you can notice that I have put NSLOG i and j.  The j comes up but the i does not....  Is my way wrong showing all the pictures that are in several folders?  I do not have any error.

Comment: What is the purpose of this line: NSString *location=@"Bottoms"@"Top"@"Right"@"Left"@"Down"@"Up"; ?

Comment: This is to retrieve the photo that I have saved.  I have created folders in the directory file.  Those are the folders IN the directory file.  I want UICollectionView to show all the pictures in those file.

Comment: What is the result when you nslog this line [allImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]?

Comment: sorry forgotten about the "a" It does not come out

Comment: But if you log that string, you get, "BottomsTopRightLeftDownUp". Is that what you want?

Comment: What? I just can't show the pictures in those directory folder.  I have those folders in directory. Cannot explain much simpler.

Comment: Do some debugging, @rdelmar is telling the truth. You may have folders on disk but you aren't iterating them or even building the path to any one of the folders.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple folders then you need to iterate over the folders and then the folder contents to process all of it.

While this line:

```
NSString *location=@"Bottoms"@"Top"@"Right"@"Left"@"Down"@"Up";
```

Is technically legal, I guess you're thinking it will do some array / iteration thing for you. It won't. It just concatenates all of the strings together. You probably want something more like:

```
NSArray *locations = @[ @"Bottoms", @"Top", @"Right", @"Left", @"Down", @"Up" ];
```

Then you can run a loop over the folders and then the contents:

```
for(NSString *folder in locations) {

    // get the folder contents 

    for(NSString *file in directoryContent) {

        // load the image

    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying incompatable pointer types sending NSArray Storng to parameter of type NSString, and when I run it it crashes.

Comment: Don't send an array when you should be using a string then. Take a step back and think about what you're doing. Use the array for iteration and the array contents for the paths.